# MySql - How to ORDER BY conditionally based on number of rows returned?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Lets suppose I have `USERS` table, and I want to return `10 USERS` whose status is not equal to `ACTIVATED`. But I want to sort output based on number of rows returned e.g. if number of rows returned is greater than 10, then I want to `order by id`, else I want to `order by date created`:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE status != 'ACTIVATED'
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
      WHEN (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS WHERE status != 'ACTIVATED') > 10 THEN id
      ELSE created
    END
ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Note that we need to cast id to INT in CASE statement, otherwise it sorts id like string.

Comment: Which, if either, of these sort orders is meant to be the one that *defines* what the `LIMIT` means?

Comment: What are the data types of id and created?

Comment: Both id and created are INT

Comment: LIMIT defines that 10 rows should be returned from sorted result.

Comment: Your query should work, whats the problem?

Comment: Well i tried this query in an online test and the test always failed.

Comment: *the test always failed*: was there an error message or just a remark *wrong answer*?

Comment: I agree that this code works - perhaps the online test is wrong.

Comment: The test said wrong answer

Comment: Perhaps the test prefers the more usual <> to != . Can you post the link to the test.

Comment: I can't share as the test was one time link sent to me as part of hiring process.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view and then use it in your count statement:

```
CREATE VIEW result AS
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE status != 'ACTIVATED'
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM result) > 10 THEN id
    ELSE created
  END
ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a syntax error on your part, so I quickly corrected your query, to limit the hassle. Notice the CASE condition and its extra brackets:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM USERS
WHERE 
    status != 'ACTIVATED'
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN ((select count(ID) FROM USERS WHERE status != 'ACTIVATED') > 10) then id
        ELSE created
    END
    ASC
LIMIT 10
```

---

**EDIT**: also agree on practice of creating a separate view for every read action that can be combined in other (sub)queries.
I.e. a separate view:

```
CREATE VIEW 'my_view' as 
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE 
    status != 'ACTIVATED'
```

By utilizing views, you can further optimize the sql execution and make it somewhat simpler overall. This is especially important when you need to combine such views to other, more complex views.

**I quickly added an example of a view syntax, so it's not production ready or a desired template to utilize when creating views.** Most views that you'll create also define security definer, invokers, in older mysql versions (and mariadb and other mysql forks) people also signify whether to utilize sql_cache or not, etc.

Comment: The extra brackets after WHEN do not serve any purpose.

Comment: True, and so is the asc keyword at the end (since it's default to sort in ascending order), the purpose of extra brackets is to limit syntax errors due to omission when writing the code